# Attaching Event Handlers in jQuery for Dynamically Loaded Items, best practices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a custom plugin, which is essentially a lightbox. I use `$('a.lightbox').lightbox();` to initialise it, and use `$(this).on('click', function);` to attach the event handler.

Prior to 1.9 you could use `.selector` to then do this `$(document).on('click', $(this).selector, function);` so that the event is attached to all current items and future items to, for example dynamically inserted items via AJAX.

After 1.9, because `.selector` is depreciated it is suggested that if you require the selector then parse it through as an option, for example: `$('a.lightbox').lightbox({selector: 'a.lightbox');` Whilst this is quite ugly, it is the recommended solution as stated in the jQuery docs.

The issue that this creates is that it's not a case of simply using different a different selector value via the `on()` method, it's more that you have to change two aspects, for example:

```
// For Live Events
$(document).on('click', option.selector, function);

// For Non-Live Events
$(this).on('click', null, function);
```

My question is this: Should *my* plugin take responsibility and allow for dynamically entered items, or should the onus be on the part of the script that inserts the new items to reinitialise the lightbox plugin and would reinitialising have any significant overheads?

Hope this makes sense, and hope this is the correct Exchange for this type of question.

Comment: Check if your plugin supports dynamic content ?

Comment: My question is about whether I should build in support for dynamic content or whether it's the responsibility of the script adding the content.

Comment: You should add to your plugin ability to support delegation

Comment: ^ Yes your plugin should be able to handle dynamic event delegation ideally..

Comment: Thanks for you comments, I guess the consensus is that my plugin needs to support delegation